# GraphQL with Data Base

Tags: node.js, postgresql, rest, model-view-controller, graphql

I just started GraphQL via tutorial and a question remains unanswered.

I intend to create an API with PostgreSQL that would be consumed by my graphQL instance but I have a question.

I have always done REST and used an MVC architecture and I wonder if it is not overkill to create methods and a router to ultimately transform them back via graphQL?

I intend to consume my API for an application in VUEJS and on mobile fluttering.

Does anyone have any advice to better prepare my API and not be redundant?

thanks in advance

Comment: graphql is just a query layer. By default, it doesn't have any knowledge how to get the data that is asked for. You need something for your resolvers. It could be a rest API underneath, like you are asking about. Or a number of other things for example, taking it directly from a database. But at the end it needs this resolver layer. I find projects like dgraph interesting because they remove the need to create your own resolvers.

Comment: What do you mean by "*create methods and a router to ultimately transform them back via graphQL*"?

Comment: thanks for your answers.
After watching several videos and discovering "Prisma" I now understood how to interface between the DBMS and the client.
However, I still have a question unanswered.
Is there a way to create your database to optimize the performance of graphQL in your Postgres system?

One way to create tables or something?

The ORM will take care of processing the models that I send it via the diagrams that I will have made upstream?
Sorry for these questions, I am documenting myself in parallel :)